# XAMPP MySQL InnoDB error

Tags: mysql, database, xampp, innodb

I know this is not a programming question per say, but I'm trying to start developing.

I'm having so much trouble with MySQL XAMPP for Mac. (OS X El Capitan Ver 10.11.6)

Here is my error log:

> 2017-06-22 08:53:05 642 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Han.local.pid ended
>
> 2017-06-23 08:59:06 757 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql
>   Warning: World-writable config file '/Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/etc/my.cnf' is ignored
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 10.1.22-MariaDB) starting as process 828 ...
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Warning] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/ is case insensitive
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: Using mutexes to ref count buffer pool pages
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: The InnoDB memory heap is disabled
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __sync_synchronize() is used for memory barrier
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.8
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] InnoDB: Using SSE crc32 instructions
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [ERROR] mysqld: Can't create/write to file '/var/folders/gt/pwvyl66n6_g9q2q76tbbzkyw0000gn/T/ibbELXWV' (Errcode: 13 "Permission denied")
>
> 2017-06-23 08:59:07 7fff7bd62000  InnoDB: Error: unable to create temporary file; errno: 13
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' init function returned error.
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [ERROR] Plugin 'InnoDB' registration as a STORAGE ENGINE failed.
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [Note] Plugin 'FEEDBACK' is disabled.
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [ERROR] Unknown/unsupported storage engine: InnoDB
>
> 2017-06-23  8:59:07 140735271018496 [ERROR] Aborting
>
> 2017-06-23 08:59:07 757 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /Applications/XAMPP/xamppfiles/var/mysql/Han.local.pid ended

And here is what I've tried:

- Changing all the permissions of the folders with Terminal Sodu.
- Restarting MySQL using the Terminal.
- Uninstalling XAMPP
- Uninstalling and deleting the XAMPP Folder
- Changing the storage engine
- Changing port 3306 to 3307

I don't know what else to try, I'm at my wits end.

Please, if there is anyone else out there that has had the same trouble as me and was able to fix it, please let me know!

The stress headache is starting! D:

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I managed to find a solution to this:
Open terminal and type:

```
sudo /Applications/XAMPP/xampfiles/xampp fix_rights
```

Also, the my.cnf doesn't like to be set to all permissions, so make it 600.

Hope this helps anyone else with the issues.